# Compare Two Lists and Create a List

Tags: python

I'm still trying to learn programming so please help me simplify this.  I'm trying to run something that looks through the indices in my list and if it finds a 1 returns "yay" (just for debugging purposes).  Here's what I have so far:

```
def replaceValues(distList, indexList):

    for i in range (1,len(indexList)):

        if indexList[i] = 1
    return "yay!"
```

However, I get a syntax error whenever I run this, which underlines the 1.  Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Python is indentation-sensitive. You have to indent it. Please refer to a starting python tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the indentation.

Comment: The privous comments should fix your issue. Otherwise, post the error information.

Comment: Look at this as you are not using equality.  http://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/comparisons.html

Comment: @user3288734 if this is the indentation, it will ALWAYS return `"yay!"`, not just if you find a `1`. You'd have to include your `return` in the `if` block by indenting it as well. Running the code above will end up with a `SyntaxError` because you don't have a `:` after your `if` block, and then a `SyntaxError` expecting an indented block after the `if` block :)

Comment: @user3288734 also be aware that the *mot juste* for testing if an element is in a collection (like a `list` or a `set` or a `dict` or etc) is the keyword `in`. You should do: `if 1 in indexList: return "Yay!"` and drop the `for` loop completely.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from incorrect indentation(fixed below), you are using `=` when you should be using `==`, and you left out a colon from your if statement.

`=` is used to assign values

`==`  evaluates equality(returning a boolean i.e `True` or `False`)

You left out a `:` in your if statement.

Corrected code:

```
def replaceValues(distList, indexList):

    for i in range (1,len(indexList)):
        if indexList[i] == 1:
            return "yay!"
```

If you don't understand exactly how Python uses **whitespace/indentation** as an integral part of it's syntax/structure and other syntax basics, then you need to get on that i.e tutorials.. A quick google should turn up many. I recommend [**Udacity**](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101) or [**Codeacademy**](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)

Answer (score 2):

There are *three* syntax errors that I see.

First, [you're using the `=` sign (assignment) when you need `==` (comparison)](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch04.html).

Second, you're missing a colon at the end of your `if` statement.

Finally, you **must*** have an indented block after your `if` statement.

All together, it should read like this:

```
if indexList[i] == 1: # double-equals and colon
    return "yay!" # This must be indented to the proper level
```

You should really go have a look at the [tutorials](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/); this is all stuff that's laid out very well there, and it's all critical to doing pretty much anything in Python.

---

<sub>*Technically, you can also follow an `if` statement with an expression on the same line (e.g. `if 1: pass`). However, I personally think this is hideous in almost every case.</sub>

Comment: To your final note: I do a lot of `try: statement; except: block` lines. Generally when I'm trying something it's `int(foo)` or `os.remove(file)` or etc. A single line of stuff to try, then a block of stuff in case it goes wrong. I use it only occasionally on `if`s, and always when I'd rather be using a switch/case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`=` is an assignment statement.  Example:

`name = "tyler"`

You should use `==` to check for equality of primitives (you're comparing integers, which are primitives).

---

Switch :

`if indexList[i] = 1`

to:

`if indexList[i] == 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
def replaceValues(distList, indexList):
    for k in range(1, len(indexList)):
        if indexList[k] == 1:            
            return "yay!"
```